# How do I use a misc function in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

Where do I store misc functions? How do I use them? Should it be a DependencyInjection? Should it just be a class and do I do something like `use Acme\Bundle\AcmeBundle\Misc\ClientIPChecker`?

Say I have a function:

```
<?php
class ClientIPChecker {
    public static function isLocal(Request $request){
        return in_array('127.0.0.1', $request->getClientIp())
    }
}
```

And I want to use this function in **two** controllers. How do I do this in Symfony2?

Comment: Use services with a namespace like Util. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: @gremo is right, define this class has a service, add the "scope: request" to the service definition to allow it access the request. Then you can perform a $this->get('util.ipchecker)->isLocal(); wherever you want

Comment: I do not agree with @gremo and Thomas Piard, this is just a function put in a class, the class is not an object. Just put it in a Misc or Util namespace and use it directly in the class

Comment: And, btw, this discussion proves that this question is Primary opinion based and that means it's off topic for SO.

Comment: You can also extend Symfony `Request` adding `isLocal` function, or just put in in a `BaseController`.

Comment: Please note that this is just an example, the idea is to have an function, that's used in 2 or more (but not all) controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a set of consistent function put them in a class/service. If functions do different things put them in the appropriate class/service. In this particular case, I'll go for either custom `Request` or custom `Controller` (probably the latter, avoding messing `app.php` or `app_dev.php`).

With custom controller this doesn't work:

```
// Automatic binding of $request parameter
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
   // Won't work with custom controller
   if ($request->isLocal)) {
       // ...
   }

   // You have to do
   if ($this->getRequest()->isLocal()) {
       // stuff
   }
}
```

**Option 1: extend Symfony  `Request`**

```
namespace My\HttpFoundation;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as BaseRequest;

class Request extends BaseRequest
{
    public function isLocal()
    {
       return in_array('127.0.0.1', $this->getClientIp());
    }
}
```

Then in `web/app.php` and `web/app_dev.php` modify:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

to be:

```
use My\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

**Option 2: create a `BaseAbstractController`** and use it instead of Symfony controller

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

abstract class BaseAbstractController extends Controller
{
    public function isRequestLocal()
    {
        return in_array('127.0.0.1', $this->getRequest()->getClientIp())
    }
}
```

**Option 3: custom service as explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)**

Comment: Please note that the function given in the question is an example. Such a function might or might not have to be connected to the Controller. Such as data handling, or converting an int to a alpha-numeric representation. Though, option 3 could be an option, but it's not really clear for me how to put this into practice.

Comment: @jeroenvisser101 I see. Then just use `JMSDiExtraBundle` (it's optional, but makes thing simpler) and define you class as usual. Then add `JMSDiExtraBundle` annotations to make it a service. In you controller retrieve the service based on its name. Look at the documentation, it's not that hard.